# Build Error in Pantheios c++ logger in Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, logging, pantheios

When I am trying to build pantheios 1.0.1-beta it gives "makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop." as the error. I have followed the given installation instructions correctly. All the environment variables were also correctly set. Can somebody help me to avoid this? I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you're doing: what directory you're in, what command you've executed, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

First, run vcvarsall.bat located in the Microsoft Visual Studio/VC directory to set the relevant environment variables. Then you should use nmake to build Pantheios. 
I think you are using mingw32-make which would give the "missing seperator" error.

Comment: I am also having this problem and using nmake helped me to solve the problem of the missing separator but I am still getting the following error
.cl -nologo -c -W4 -WX  -O1 -MTd -D_DEBUG -Zi -Fd.\util.bailout.mt.debug.pdb   -DWIN64 -DPANTHEIOS_NO_AUTO_INIT    -I..\..\include -I"C:\stlsoft-1.9.
112\include"   -Fo.\util.bailout.mt.debug.obj ..\..\src\util\bailout.c
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.

I have my STLSOFT and PANTHEIOS_ROOT set.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same problem. Perhaps I can resurrect this question to get help. The issue is in beta 212 for myself.

```
D:\Develop\api\pantheios-1.0.1-beta212\build\vc10>make
makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Irritatingly, the instructions mention a visual studio project file pantheios.vc6.dsw, but according to http://sourceforge.net/projects/pantheios/forums/forum/475313/topic/1674325 it was forgotten once, and by the looks of things, forgotten forever.

I'm using make 3.81 on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010.

Looking at the make file, the directives seem incorrect. I replaced all of the directives by removing the preceding '!', so `!ifndef` becomes `ifndef`. There are quite a few replacements needed.

The next error I get is the following:

```
D:\Develop\api\pantheios-1.0.1-beta212\build\vc10>make
cl   -nologo -c -W4 -WX  -O1  -MTd -D_DEBUG -Zi -Fd.pdb   -DWIN32  -DPANTHEIOS_NO_AUTO_INIT  -I..\..\include -I"D:\Develop\SDK and Libraries\stlsoft-1
.9.109\include\include"     -Fo.\util.bailout.mt.debug.obj ..\..\src\util\bailout.c
Exception: compiler not found cl
make: *** [.\util.bailout.mt.debug.obj] Error 1
```

If I change the makefile CC definition to point to cl.exe, I start getting missing DLL errors, so now I've stopped because I feel I'm moving in the complete wrong direction.

Comment: Use `nmake` instead of `make` to build.